# Use oauth flow to create GCP service account?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform

I'm looking to provide a service to people using GCP.

Given that I'll be accessing their GCP monitoring APIs from my server, it seems like that would be best done using a service account. That way it's not tied to an individual user, and won't stop working if that user is removed from their organization.

Creating a service account manually is not too complicated, but definitely more complicated than just presenting the user with an oauth permissions flow.

Is there any way to create a GCP service account using an oauth flow so that I don't have to force the user to create one manually with the correct permissions?

I've looked around, and can't find any documentation on this, which leads me to believe that it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can create service accounts programatically with the [projects.serviceAccounts.create](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/create) API call. This call must be made by a user authorized with iam.serviceAccounts.create permission (e.g. owner or iam.serviceAccountAdmin role). Code to do this would look like:

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
import httplib2
credentials = GET_YOUR_USER_CREDS()
http_auth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
iam_client = googleapiclient.discovery.build('iam', 'v1', http=http_auth())
iam_client.projects().serviceAccounts().create(name="projects/PROJECT_ID", body={"accountId":"SERVICE-ACCOUNT-ID"}).execute()
```